# Implementing RAML documentation in django project

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, api-design, raml

I already set up RAML for django .  Its reading my urls and showing the documentation page in my localhost. Now i need to write the RAML Code for documentation where i define all the requests and responses . I dont know where to write the RAML code in my django project .

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from users import views
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view
from rest_framework_raml.renderers import RAMLRenderer, RAMLDocsRenderer

schema_view = get_schema_view(
    title='Example API',
    renderer_classes=[RAMLRenderer, RAMLDocsRenderer])


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/users/emailsignup/', views.SignUp.as_view()),
    url(r'^api/v1/users/userget/', views.UserDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^api/v1/users/emailsignin/', views.SignIn.as_view()),
    url(r'^api/v1/users/emailsignout/', views.SignOut.as_view()),
    url(r'^raml/$', schema_view),
]
```

I need to know where to write the raml code in the project and how to give its url

Comment: Which RAML package are you using? If it's [django-rest-raml](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-raml) it doesn't yet support examples.

Comment: i do have a complete raml document in a folder . tell me how to include that folder in my django project directory and how to write my url for it.